# Certificate issue: mvn exec:java sees it, java -jar does not

Tags: java, security, certificate

I have installed a security certificate and I have a problem. When I run my code with

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.myproject.MyClass"
```

it works fine. But when I try to package things in a JAR, and run it with:

```
java -jar MyProject.jar
```

I get a

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 38 more
```

I create the jar with:

```
mvn clean install jar:jar
```

On the same level as the jar I have a directory called `lib`, and in `lib` I have all the dependencies. The dependencies were added to the MANIFEST.MF file in my jar, the path for them is correct, the lines are not too long (one dependency on each line).

Maven and Java use the same JDK. They should normally have the same dependencies on the classpath, too. But it seems that `java -jar` ignores the certificate.

Can someone explain why this happens ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this ?

https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

and

http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target

this will solve your issue

Comment: I have already installed the certificate using keytool.

When running the same code via Maven, it has no problem finding the certificate. Only when running the code packaged in a jar. 

The server not being trusted doesn't seem to be the problem here.